# Java regex, IllegalStateException: No match found

Tags: java, regex

I spent a bit of time looking for the answer, but I couldn't find it, so, here's the question:

I'm getting this error:

```
    StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw  
    exceptionjava.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
        at extra.regex.checkRegex(regex.java:21)
```

And here's the code

```
    public class regex {
        public static String checkRegex(String check, String regex)
        {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(check);
            m.matches();
            return m.group(1);
        }
    }
```

I'm calling `checkRegex()` with this:

```
    String query = request.getQueryString();//this query looks like "sel=45"
    String regulex = "#^(.+)#"; //even this guy returns no matches

    //out.println(query); //it is is not null
    String result = regex.checkRegex(query, regulex);

    out.println(result);
```

I've seen a few questions here, but all were about missing `m.matches()` or `m.find()`, but I've triple checked that.

Comment: What does `matches` return?

Comment: This is explained in the Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `matches()` returns a boolean, an extra check needed?

@Reimeus, I've checked that via regex101, unfortunately, it matches completely

Comment: "*I've seen a few questions here, but all were about missing m.matches() or m.find()*" do you know what is purpose of these methods? Do you know difference between them?

Comment: regex101 doesn't do `matches`, it does `find`.

Comment: changed `matches()` to `find()`, which also returns boolean, but it seems that the regex is still not matching with any substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down your pattern:

```
"#^(.+)#"
```

- `#^` - Literal string
- `(.+)` - Any character (may or may not match line terminators) 1 or more times
- `#` - Literal string

So why does `sel=45` fail to match?  The `String` does not begin with `"#^"` and does not end with `"#"`.

It would seem you want to capture data in between `"#"` that may or may not be there (You need to clarify this).  The following pattern accomplishes that:

```
"#?([^#]+)#?"
```

This will match `sel=45` and will match `#sel=45#`

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String regulex = "#?([^#]+)#?"; //even this guy returns no matches

    System.out.println(checkRegex("#sel=45#", regulex));
    System.out.println(checkRegex("sel=45", regulex));
}

public static String checkRegex(String check, String regex) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(check);
    return m.matches() ? m.group(1): null;
}
```

Results:

```
sel=45
sel=45
```

Comment: Oh, I used `#` as a delimiter, but it was not required, and this messed it all up. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You shoud use `m.group()` in an `if` block:

```
     if(m.matches()) {
        return m.group(1);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed the error, but the value is still null

Comment: @AlexShereshovets and what schould the result should be?

Comment: with this regex - it should return the whole query, I know, this is pointless, but it takes nothing to change the expression)

Comment: @AlexShereshovets Post example text you want to parse and show part which you want to find. Also `#^` doesn't make sense because `^` represents start of string, which but if it is placed right after `#` it means that it will never match start of string. This simply can't work.

Comment: @Pshemo for example, I want to find `121123123234` in `sel=121123123234`, so I will use this `#[^=]+=([0-9]+)#` or `#sel=([0-9]+)#`, but I tried to make it simpler and throw away cases when my regex could be wrong

Comment: Try the regex "=(\\d+)"

Answer (score 0):

This regex expression

```
  String regulex = "^#(.+)#";
```

will match

```
    String query = "#sel=45#";
```

This combination doesn't make sense `#^`. `^` indicates the beginning of string, nothing can be before it. And if you `query` does not contain `#` it won't match `regulex`.